# Does Realm support set max record counts

Tags: realm

Does Realm support set max record counts?

My requirement is simple, I have a lot of data coming in on daily basis, but I just want to store last 3 months records, so when it's full, it will delete old record and append the new one, automatically.

Tried google but couldn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that isn't supported directly, although it should be fairly simple to implement yourself.

On Android it would look something like this:

```
realm.beginTransaction();

// Delete all records more than 90 days old
realm.where(Record.class)
  .lessThan("created", calculateCutoff())
  .findAll()
  .deleteAllFromRealm();

// Create new record
Record r = realm.createObject(Record.class);
r.setCreated(new Date())
...
realm.commitTransaction();
```